# Baseurl inside img tags not getting parsed in Jekyll

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I've set `baseurl: /my-url` in `config.yml` and am using `{{ site.baseurl }}` when declaring all relative links like so:

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/cloud-banners/service.png">
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/blah-blah/">
<link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/blah-blah/">
<use xlink:href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/icons/doctype-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#gpres"></use>
```

For whatever reason, when Jekyll parses my .md and .html files, it only recognizes the `{{ site.baseurl }}` tag in anchor and link tags, but not in anything else (like images/svgs). So when I look at my outputted site, none of my assets are rendering correctly because the HTML literally renders the double curly braces and site.baseurl rather than replacing it with the correct text (`/my-url`).

Any ideas on where I should be looking to debug? I've definitely got the requisite YAML front matter to indicate to Jekyll that it should be looking at the file. And I need to use the `baseurl` solution because I'm hosting my Jekyll site on Github Pages, so relative URLs won't work otherwise.

Comment: Have you got a repo URL for us to debug?

Comment: Apologies- forgot to update this. The issue was that I was using `{{ page.content }}` in my layout file instead of `{{ content }}` - when I switched it, everything got parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using `{{ page.content }}` in my layout file instead of `{{ content }}` - when I switched it, everything got parsed correctly.